# Flutter give container rounded border

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, user-interface

I'm making a `Container()`, I gave it a border, but it would be nice to have rounded borders.

This is what I have now:

```
Container(
      width: screenWidth / 7,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        border: Border.all(
          color: Colors.red[500],
        ),
      ),
      child: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              '6',
              style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.red[500],
                  fontSize: 25),
            ),
            Text(
             'sep',
              style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.red[500]),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
```

I tried putting `ClipRRect` on it, but that crops the border away. Is there a solution for this?

Answer (score 554, accepted):

Try using the property `borderRadius` from `BoxDecoration`

Something like

```
Container(
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    border: Border.all(
      color: Colors.red[500],
    ),
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20))
  ),
  child: ...
)
```

Comment: `BorderRadius.circular(20)` can be used as shorthand for  `BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20))`

Answer (score 108):

To make it completely circle:

```
Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        shape: BoxShape.circle,
      ),
    )
```

To make it a circle at selected spots:

```
Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
            topRight: Radius.circular(40.0),
            bottomRight: Radius.circular(40.0),
            topLeft: Radius.circular(40.0),
            bottomLeft: Radius.circular(40.0)),
      ),
      child: Text("hello"),
    ),
```

or

```
  Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
      ),
      child: ...
    )
```

Answer (score 44):

It can be done in several ways.

- If you have a simple rounded corner to implement use `ClipRRect`,
  `ClipOval`
- If you want to have more command over the rounded corneres use  `BoxDecoration` inside the `Container`

#### ClipRRect

[image]

```
 ClipRRect(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
    child: Container(height: 100, width: 100, color: Colors.orange)),
```

#### ClipOval

[image]

```
ClipOval(
    child: Container(height: 100, width: 100, color: Colors.orange)),
```

#### BoxDecoration

- #### Border across all the corners

[image]

```
 Container(
   decoration: BoxDecoration(
   borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
   color: Colors.orange),
   height: 100,
   width: 100,
 );
```

- #### Border in a particular corner

[image]

```
 Container(
    decoration: const BoxDecoration(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
       topLeft: Radius.circular(40),
       bottomRight: Radius.circular(40)),
      color: Colors.orange),
    height: 100,
    width: 100,
 ),
```

- #### Border in a particular axis

[image]

```
  Container(
    decoration: const BoxDecoration(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.horizontal(
        right: Radius.circular(60),
        ),
      color: Colors.orange),
    height: 100,
    width: 100,
  );
```

Answer (score 21):

You can use like this. If you want border for all the corners you can use like bellow.

```
Container(
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    color: Colors.white,
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
      Radius.circular(12.0),
    ),
  ),
),
```

If you want rounded borders for selected sides only you can use like below.

```
Container(
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    color: Colors.white,
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
      topLeft: Radius.circular(10),
      topRight: Radius.circular(10),
    ),
  ),
  child: Text('Text'),
),
```

Answer (score 14):

You can use `ClipRRect` Widget:

```
ClipRRect (
  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
  child: Container(
                    height: 25,
                    width: 40,
                    color: const Color(0xffF8742C),
                    child: Align(
                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                        child: Text("Withdraw"))),
          )
```

Answer (score 11):

Enhancement for the above answer.

```dart
Container(
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    border: Border.all(
      color: Colors.red[500],
    ),
   borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20) // use instead of BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20))
  ),
  child: ...
)
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: Sorry, I miss that.

Answer (score 8):

To make a complete circle just use shape property :

```
Container(
   padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4),
   decoration: BoxDecoration(
     shape: BoxShape.circle,
     color: Colors.black,
   ),                            
   child: Icon(
      Icons.add,
      size: 15.0,
      color: Colors.white,
     ),
```

[image: Here is picture]

Answer (score 6):

```
Container(
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
      border: Border.all(
        color: HexColor('#C88A3D'),
        width: 3.0
      )
    ),
    child: Container(
      decoration: new BoxDecoration(borderRadius:
      BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
      color: Colors.white,),
    )
  ),
```

Answer (score 4):

The key here is to add a `BorderRadius`:

```
Container(    
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    border: Border.all(
      color: Colors.red[340],
     ),
     borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(35),
   ),
   child: `enter code here`
),
```

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn and eventually apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive-feedback/upvotes from users, when the code is explained.

Answer (score 4):

just with put this at the **Container**

```
Container(
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(30))
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Just to show another way to do the same thing.

Might be useful when needs to use InkWell around Container.

```
Material(
 shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
   borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
 ),
 child: Container(
   height: 100,
   width: 150,
 ),
);
```

Answer (score 2):

Just simply use circle shape `shape: BoxShape.circle` in `BoxDecoration`.
All code be like

```
Container(
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    shape: BoxShape.circle
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SizedBox(
                            child: (Container(
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  color: Colors.grey,
                                  border: Border.all(
                                    color: Colors.grey,
                                  ),
                                  borderRadius:
                                      BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20))),
                              child: Column(
                                mainAxisAlignment:
                                    MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                children: [
                                  Row(
                                    mainAxisAlignment:
                                        MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                                    crossAxisAlignment:
                                        CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                    children: [
                                      Text('00'),

                                      Padding(
                                        padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
                                            2.0, 0, 0, 0),
                                        child: Container(
                                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                            shape: BoxShape.circle,
                                            color: Colors.white,
                                          ),
                                          child: CustomText(
                                            "2",
                                            color: Colors.black,
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ), // text
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            )),
                            width: 60,
                          ),
```

Answer (score 1):

use decoration property to give radius in Container

```
 decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
            topRight: Radius.circular(15),
            bottomLeft: Radius.circular(15)),
      ),

or 

Container(
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    color: Colors.red,
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
      Radius.circular(12.0),

    ),
  ),
),
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).