# flutter: how to get a rounded container in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I'm new in flutter and I want to make a round container. I have done this but I don't know how to adjust the value to adapt it. Is there a better solution? Thanks in advance.

```
Widget Cube() {
  return Container(
    width: 70, height: 70,
    child: Container(
      width: 64, height: 64,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: CalendarColor.blue,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
          Radius.circular(32),
        )
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

what I want is like this.
[image]

Comment: Try this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57777737/flutter-give-container-rounded-border

Comment: could you please add an Image ... what do you want ..

Comment: can you make it clear what you mean by 'the value to adapt it' ?

Comment: because I can only adjust the argument of Radius.circular() to make it looks like a circle. but I am not sure if it's exactly a circle.@Henok

Answer (score 2):

```
Container(
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    shape: BoxShape.circle //This will make container round
  )
)
```

Comment: if i know the radius of the circle, how to set the height and width of the `container` then

Comment: Container(width: <width>, height: <height>)

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a better solution?

How about `FoatingActionButton`?

```
FloatingActionButton(
                backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
                elevation: 0.0,
                child: Text("15", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
                onPressed: () {})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use RawMaterialButton for more options like this:

```
RawMaterialButton(
      elevation: 2.0,
      fillColor:  Colors.black,
      shape: CircleBorder(),
      onPressed: () {});
      },
    )
```